# Disconnect users from a voice channel for being defeaned for 10 minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So my problem is I want to create a bot that disconnects people from a VC on Discord server if they are being defeaned for 10 minutes.
I know a thing or two about programming because I learnt it in school, but I never used python.

I have a working music bot, with `index.js` and everything. So I was wondering if you could help me write a code for that I can paste into it so it'll work?
Thanks in advance!

I found this code:

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
  if (newState.deafened && newState.member.manageable) {
    newState.kick();
  }
});
```

But it didn't work for some reason, and it wouldn't even let me set user afk time.
You don't have to fix this, you can write a new code instead for the whole concept :)

Answer (score -1):

First of all, `VoiceState` doesn't have a property called 'deafened'. You can use `VoiceState.selfDeaf` instead, which returns a boolean.

Second of all, `VoiceState.kick()` wont do anything, as it's not a method of `VoiceState`. Assuming you want to kick the member from the vc, you can use `VoiceState.disconnect()`.

You can read the VoiceState documentation [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/VoiceState)